# How does bigO(5*2^n + 1000n^100) become bigO(2^n)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I have just started "Cracking the Coding Interview" by Gayle Macdowell. In this BigO topic, It  says we should drop the non-dominant term.

O(n^2 + n) becomes O(n^2) and O(n + log n) becomes O(n).

Well, I understand that. If we suppose the value of n to be some large number then we can ignore the smaller result since, it will be comparatively much more smaller than the larger one.

But, in this case how can O(5*2^n + 1000n^100) become O(2^n)) ?

Isn't n^100 dominant than 2 ^n ?

Comment: big-O is about how something scales over time; whether there's a big constant or small constant doesn't matter, since the other part of the scale increases exponentially in this case.

Comment: Nitpick: It's not `BigO(n)`, it's just `O(n)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

n^100, or n raised to any constant, does not dominate 2^n.

Comment: if n = 100, isn't ( 100 ^ 100 > 2 ^ 100 ) ? or, do you mean that the constant(i.e 100) in n ^ 100 is dropped ?

Comment: For a sample size of n = 100, an algorithm that requires 2^n operations will be faster than an algorithm that requires n^100.  But Big-O notation is not about the number of operations for any fixed size - it is a way of describing the way the algorithm scales as n becomes arbitrarily large (i.e. approaches infinity).

Comment: It seems little easier now. Thanks!